# how to solve strange error after installing telethon?

Tags: python, telethon

well as I said I installed telethon

```
pip install telethon                                                                                                                                                                                          
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: telethon in /home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyaes in /home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from telethon) (1.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa in /home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from telethon) (4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from rsa->telethon) (0.4.8)
```

and now when I want to use it

```
import telethon 
print(telethon.__version__)
```

I'll get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/testtelethone", line 1, in <module>
    import telethon 
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client.telegramclient import TelegramClient
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/client/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .downloads import DownloadMethods
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telethon/client/downloads.py", line 16, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import BaseConnector as BaseConnector
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . import hdrs, http, payload
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/http.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .http_parser import HeadersParser as HeadersParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/http_parser.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .helpers import NO_EXTENSIONS, BaseTimerContext
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 607, in <module>
    class CeilTimeout(async_timeout.timeout):
TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str
```

I guess it python didn't recognize it but what should I do?

Comment: Please include the actual text of your code and other stuff, not images - images are very unhelpful for allowing others to debug/test. Are you getting this error from just the code in your image, just `import telethon; print(telethon.__version__)`?

Comment: Yes, and it looks like the error comes from the first line `import telethon`

Comment: I tried on Python 3.10.2 on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit and could not reproduce your error. Please tell us what version of Python you're using, on what version of what OS. If the version is also a 3.10.x and you're also on 64-bit Windows, you may also want to include the output of `pip freeze`, or you should try the same in a new and otherwise empty environment (using `virtualenv`, `venv`, `conda`, etc.)

Comment: Hi
I'm using python 3.10.5 and my os is Linux 5.9.0-kali1-amd64